# All column families are not mapped from Cassandra keyspace to hive database

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise

I am using cassandra which is integrated with hadoop hive.

I have these two columnfamilies in my keyspace test-

```
1)CF_1
create COLUMNFAMILY CF_1 (key uuid primary key, time varchar,type varchar);

2)CF_2
create COLUMNFAMILY CF_2 (id varchar, time timestamp,  data varchar, primary key(id,time));
```

So the hive maps only CF_1 from my cassandra keyspace to hive table. I think the other column family(CF_2) is not mapped because it has composite primary key.

Either I believe there is currently no support for CFs with composite keys in DataStax enterprise kit or I am missing something. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You may need use CqlStorageHandler.

Check the following blog about how the CQL3 tables are handled in hive
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-table-support-in-hadoop-pig-and-hive